# How good is this approximation?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I have an integral
$$\int_0^a\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{\mathrm{d}f(p,x)}{\mathrm{d}x}\mathrm{e}^{-\int_0^x\mathrm{d}x'\,g(p, x')},$$
where $f$ and $g$ are both strictly positive real functions. At small $x$, the exponential term is almost unity, while at large $x$, the exponential term suppreses the entire integrand. This exponential cut-off becomes important at $$\int_0^{x_0}\mathrm{d}x'\,g(p, x')=1.$$
Assuming $a>x_0$ Thus I write the first integral as
$$\int_0^{x_0}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{\mathrm{d}f(p,x)}{\mathrm{d}x}=f(p,x_0)-f(p,0).$$
How good is the above approximation? The whole point of making such approximation is that the first integral is not analytically solvable without making some level of approximations.

Comment: So you're approximating $e^{-x}$ with the indicator function $1_{x\le 1}$. On the face of it that looks kind of bad, but how bad it actually is depends on how the mass of the remaining $\frac{df}{dx}$ term is distributed.

Comment: In the worst case when $\frac{df}{dx}$ is a delta function just before $x_0$ the relative error is $172\%$...